# How to make a new device explorer folder for android studio on Mac

Tags: android-studio, missing-data, android-device-explorer

I haven't used Android Studio in a long time. I'm starting to use it again to develop Flutter apps but I no longer have the Device Explorer. I looked everywhere on my computer but it's no where to be found. Is there a way to create a new DeviceExplorer folder and put new emulators in it?